How do I troubleshoot “failed to write to … dnsmasq.leases“?
One laptop, running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS cannot connect to the WiFi router. In the router’s logs I’m seeing the following:
Oct 16 20:52:54 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(645): wl0.1: Deauth_ind 28:B2:BD:5D:75:73, status: 0, reason: Previous authentication no longer valid (2), rssi:-66
Oct 16 20:53:32 dnsmasq-dhcp[15695]: failed to write /var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases: No space left on device (retry in 60s)
Oct 16 20:54:32 dnsmasq-dhcp[15695]: failed to write /var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases: No space left on device (retry in 60s)

The laptop has 11G empty, is this an issue with the router or the laptop?

Run df -h to see how much space is available. Some of it can be unused, but reserved, and so, unavailable. EXT4 filesystems reserve 5% by default.

It turned out to be a router issue. I was able to use a machine that was connected to download the router settings, do a hard reset on the router and then re-import my settings.
I also realized that the machine in question (not mine) had been ignoring system update prompts rather than running them. Corrective guidance was offered on that front.
